Would creating vapor barrier in crawl space work?
After noticing a decline in air quality following the renovation, I decided to remove a section of the parquet flooring. Underneath, I found a significant layer of dust and sand on the wooden beams. Beneath the beams, there's about 15 cm of debris and sand. The crawl space appears dry, but I need to investigate further. Below that, there's a thin layer of concrete separating my ground-floor apartment from the basement.
Would installing a plastic vapor barrier over the sand help resolve this issue?

Is the issue the air quality?   I don't think the air is affected by what is under the floor, unless you have a very porous floor.  In that case the floor is the issue.

Yes, it's porous and shifts because it's resting on wooden beams.

Sounds like you need a better constructed floor.

A contractor I spoke with today suggested the same idea—creating a cement screed over the beams.
